# WP magic fields query_posts

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to display titles from posts of type 'products' with that have a custom field "product_category" (dropdown) with value "food".

When the "food" field is set to type "text" everything is fine. When I change the type of this 
field to "dropdown" nothing appears.

To create custom page and custom fields I use Magic Fields plugin in Wordpress.

Here's the code:

```
     <?php
    global $wp_query;
    query_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'products',
          'meta_query'  => array(
                   array(
                    'key'    => 'product_category',
                    'value'  => 'food',
                    )
                ))    
);
    while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php $key = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'title'); ?>
        <li <?php post_class(); ?>><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php if($key) { echo $key[0]; } else { the_title(); }; ?></a></li>
        <?php
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
    ?>
```

Comment: You talk about the field type issue but post no code for it. How are you generating the field?

Comment: I created custom page type using Magic Fields plugin. This post type is setting the "Capability type" as a page.

Comment: Did you check your database? `wp_postmeta` table should have proper values for posts you want to list under `meta_key` = `product_category`.

Comment: It seems that it is ok with wp_postmeta values.

Answer (score 1):

> **use meta_key and meta_value**

```
<?php
    global $wp_query;
    query_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'products',
          'meta_query'  => array(
                   array(
                    'meta_key'    => 'product_category',
                    'meta_value'  => 'food',
                    )
                ))    
);
?>
```

Comment: Unfortunelty this code doesn't work. Whatever I type in 'meta_key' and 'meta_value" the Wordpress will display all my products pages.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the parameter metacompare to the array `(meta_compare => 'like')` because on table `wp_postmeta` the `key_value` is saved like `"a:1:{i:0;s:7:"Food";}"`

so

you should change to:

```
query_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'products',
        'meta_key'    => 'product_category',
        'meta_value'  => 'food',
        'meta_compare' => 'like'
                ))    
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `meta_query` instead. Make sure you try both `products` and `product` as your `post_type` parameter.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'product_category',
            'value' => 'food'
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Also, don't use `query_posts`. [Here's why](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).